# Как получить PID процесса? Windows

Tags: java

Один человек навёл меня на PID. Это поможет модифицировать мою программу.
Мне нужно узнать, как получить PID у процессов Windows, затем, как с помощью PID переключаться между окнами и посылать нажатия клавиш.

Comment: Ваш вопрос больше похож на просьбу написать немаленькую программу, Только неясно. 1. А что вы делали чтобы это у вас получилось? 2. Нет конкретики: какую именно программу надо модифицировать, переключаться между какими окнами (внутри одного процесса или разных) и т.д.

Comment: На Java это потребует немаленьких строк кода. Не так давно реализовал переключение между программами в vb .net - всего несколько строк кода + нажатие клавиш + клики мышкой + вставка в поле значение из буфера - там всё гораздо проще.

Comment: К примеру, я сканирую логи кое какой игры и при обнаружении в логах КОЕ ЧЕГО я вывожу это на консоль программы, но так же мне нужно, чтобы программа смогла переключиться на окно игры и сделать скриншот (имитируя нажатие соответствующей клавиши) . Пока что создание скриншота работает только на уровне класса Robot, т.е. если окно не открыто скриншот не будет сделан. У меня не было самостоятельных попыток реализовать то, что мне нужно, так как я даже не знаю с чего начинать, поэтому и спросил совета здесь. Как написал пользователь ниже, это не для начинающих, но а что же делать. Как учить?

Comment: @Prototype-TV читать статьи/документацию/вопросы (на большом SO) по JNA (это легче, чем JNI), разбираться, пробовать, тыкаться. задавать здесь и на EngSO конкретные вопросы, если что-то не получается. Займет какое-то время, но другого пути нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить список процессов несложно, это можно сделать, например, с использованием утилиты `tasklist`, входящей в Windows (на Linux есть своя подобная):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String line;
  try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir")  
                                          + "\\system32\\tasklist.exe");
    BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(
                              new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(line);
    input.close();
  } catch (Exception x) { x.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Подобным же образом можно запустить любую другую программу. 
А вот управлять окнами других, уже работающих, приложений (переключать фокус, открывать/закрывать) из программы на Java не так просто. Это можно делать с помощью стандартного JNI, или более продвинутого JNA, но в двух словах описать процесс сложно. Читайте соотв. документацию. Добавлю, что на мой взгляд, это задача не для начинающего.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что здесь требуется более высокий уровень владения языком. Нужно же идти дальше.

Comment: Отлично, с Вашей помощью я решил одну часть задачи. PID теперь мы знаем. =)

Comment: @Prototype-TV, рад, что смог помочь. А благодарность можно еще выразить путём помечания ответа, как принятого :)