# Получения фокуса окна по PID

Tags: java

В [данной](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613540/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-pid-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-windows) теме я узнал, как получить PID процесса. Из выведенного списка все процессы Java отображаются просто java.exe, но если мне нужно получить конкретно окно по PID процесса и сфокусироваться на нём, то как это сделать? Я в этом направлении вообще ничего не знаю, поэтому предоставить своих вариантов реализации не могу.

Comment: Вопрос всё ещё актуальный.